# Unusual Error with JavaFX ObservableList

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, observablelist

I'm writing a GUI for a school project and Layout Managers pissed me off so I switched to JavaFX. I'm Trying to populate a TableView and TableColumns with example data for now, but I'm getting a weird error with Observable List.

Error as Follows:

```
Error:(84, 27) java: method addAll in interface javafx.collections.ObservableList<E> cannot be applied to given types;
      required: javafx.scene.control.TableColumn<capture#1 of ?,?>[]
      found: javafx.scene.control.TableColumn<Pizza,java.lang.String>,javafx.scene.control.TableColumn<Pizza,java.lang.String>,javafx.scene.control.TableColumn<Pizza,java.lang.String>
      reason: varargs mismatch; javafx.scene.control.TableColumn<Pizza,java.lang.String> cannot be converted to javafx.scene.control.TableColumn<capture#1 of ?,?>
Error:(85, 33) java: incompatible types: javafx.collections.ObservableList<Pizza> cannot be converted to javafx.collections.ObservableList<capture#2 of ?>
```

My Current Code:

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;


import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class GUIController implements Initializable {

    //<editor-fold desc="A Bunch of FXML stuff(Leave Folded if you want to live)">
    @FXML
    private RadioButton small;

    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup Size;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton medium;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton large;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox cheese;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox pepper;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox olives;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox pine;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox tomato;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox mushroom;

    @FXML
    private TableView<?> table;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Pizza, String> tableSize;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Pizza, String> tableDesc;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Pizza, String> tablePrice;

    @FXML
    private Button submit;

    @FXML
    private Button admin;
    //</editor-fold>

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        //ADD CODE HERE!!!
        tableStuff();

    }

    public void tableStuff(){
        tableDesc = new TableColumn<>("Description");
        tableSize = new TableColumn<>();
        tablePrice = new TableColumn<>();
        tableSize.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("size"));
        tableDesc.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("desc"));
        tablePrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Price"));
        table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().addAll(tableSize,tableDesc,tablePrice);
        table.setItems(tableFill());
    }

    public ObservableList<Pizza> tableFill() {  //TODO: create input into pizzas
        ObservableList<Pizza> pizzas = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        //char size, Boolean cheese, Boolean pepperoni, Boolean olives, Boolean pineapple, Boolean tomatoes, Boolean mushrooms
        pizzas.add(new Pizza("S", "Stuff", "$1.1 Mil."));
        pizzas.add(new Pizza("S", "Stuff", "$1.1 Mil."));
        return pizzas;
    }
}
```

And my current FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="734.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="GUIController">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints maxHeight="550.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="329.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints maxHeight="536.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="444.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints maxHeight="536.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="96.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <GridPane prefHeight="342.0" prefWidth="600.0">
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="54.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="54.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="84.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="109.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="159.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="178.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="178.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="178.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <RadioButton fx:id="small" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="Small" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <toggleGroup>
                  <ToggleGroup fx:id="Size" />
               </toggleGroup>
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="100.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton fx:id="medium" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Medium" toggleGroup="$Size" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="100.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton fx:id="large" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Large" toggleGroup="$Size" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="100.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </RadioButton>
            <Label text="Pizza Size" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="BOTTOM">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <CheckBox fx:id="cheese" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="76.0" text="Cheese" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="100.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </CheckBox>
            <CheckBox fx:id="pepper" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Pepperoni" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="100.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </CheckBox>
            <CheckBox fx:id="olives" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Black Olives" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="100.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </CheckBox>
            <CheckBox fx:id="pine" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Pineapple" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="100.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </CheckBox>
            <CheckBox fx:id="tomato" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Tomatoes" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="100.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </CheckBox>
            <CheckBox fx:id="mushroom" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Mushrooms" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="100.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </CheckBox>
            <Label text="Pizza Toppings" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.valignment="BOTTOM">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
      <TableView fx:id="table" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="tableSize" prefWidth="75.0" text="Size" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="tableDesc" prefWidth="434.0" text="Description" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="tablePrice" prefWidth="75.0" text="Price" />
        </columns>
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
      </TableView>
      <GridPane GridPane.rowIndex="2">
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="194.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="69.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="413.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="413.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="143.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="69.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="submit" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="184.0" text="Submit Order" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" />
            <Button fx:id="admin" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="30.0" styleClass="buttonWithImage" stylesheets="@Style.css" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which line is the error coming from? Can you trim this down to just the directly relevant code? See [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private TableView<?> table;
```

Replace `?` with the exact type of the table rows: `Pizza`.

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot... Thanks! That fixed that part but now I'm getting another weird one.

Comment: New problem = new question. And again, please reduce your code to a [mcve] when you post the new question.

Comment: Will do next time, also I figured out what was causing it. Thanks for the help.